# How to calculate custom array values in lightning component

Tags: lightning

I have tried to calculate sum of custom array values in lightning component parent & child Using Application and Component events. Able to get from entered child values in parent. But calculation i am getting struggled, Pls guide me how to solve this.

### Component:

```
<aura:component >     
    <aura:attribute name="arrvals" type="integer[]" default="1,2,3,4,5"/>    
    <aura:registerEvent name="sum" type="c:SumAppEvent"/>     
    <aura:handler name="sumres" event="c:SumCompEvent" action="{!c.sumVal}"/>

    <aura:iteration var="num" items="{!v.arrvals}" aura:id="ipv" indexVar="index">
        <c:myListComponent />         
    </aura:iteration>

    <ui:button aura:id="addbtn" label="Calculate" press="{!c.calculate}" />

    <br/>
    Sum of the Value : <ui:outputNumber aura:id="totalValue" value="{!v.totalValue}" />    
</aura:component>
```

### Controller.js

```
 ({
        sumVal : function(component, event, helper) {



        var txtval = event.getParam("resval");          
        console.log('got value from child',txtval);
        debugger;  

         for (var i = 0,sum = 0; i <txtval.length; i++) {
             sum += txtval;
         } 
         console.log('sum +++++++',sum);      
    },                     

    calculate : function(component, event, helper) {                

            $A.get("e.c:SumAppEvent").fire();                                                 

    } , 
})
```

Advance Thanks
Sivasakthi

Comment: are you getting any values here `console.log(arrvals);`

Answer (score 1):

```
({       
    calculate : function(component) {

       try {     
            debugger;
            var numbers=component.find("index+ip").get("v.value");
            console.log(numbers); 
            var arrlist =component.get("v.arrvals");
            console.log(arrvals);            
            var totalval=0;            
            for(var i=0; i<arrlist.length; i++) { 

                totalval += parseInt(arrlist[i]) ;
                console.log(totalval);                
            }          
                component.set('v.totalValue',totalval);            
        }                           
        catch (e) {
            alert('Exception : '  + e);
        }     
    } ,
})
```

Try this code. It will help you.